# Integrating Mobile Express Checkout on IOS

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I was using Paypal to make payments from my application using [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/). Now I want to enable users to make card payments using Paypal. I have found that to implement this feature I have to move to [MPECL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/). When I am using MPL I used to get call backs regarding the payment status whether its success or failure within my app. Now my issue is

1. If I use MPECL will I get callbacks to my IOS app about the payment
   status?
2. Are there any nice tutorials in integrating MPECL in IOS/Android?
3. Also is it possible to use MPL and still accept card payments from
       user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) By callbacks are you referring to IPN notifications?  If so, then yes, you'll get them the same way, although the txn_type value may be different.

2) According to [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions), MPL and MPECL have been replaced by [PayPal iOS](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/) and [Android](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/) SDK's.  I'd recommend using those instead.  There are samples included with the SDK's.

3) Yes, users will be able to pay via PayPal or a credit card when going through the payment flow.  If you want to process credit cards directly within your app you can use the [new REST API for credit cards](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) or you could use [PayPal Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wpp).

Comment: Those SDKs are only available in the US.

Comment: @AndroidDev what is the right library for android outside US and UK